# How to create a combo box actionListener?

Tags: java, jcombobox

How do I create a combo box action listener?
I have the following so far:

```
myCombo = new JComboBox();
myCombo.addActionListener();
```

I am not sure how to proceed, it seems that it is different from the one used for the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 myCombo.addActionListener(new actionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eventSource) {
   JComboBox combo = (JComboBox) myCombo.getSource();
   Object selected = combo.getSelectedItem();
   if("whatever...") {

}
}
}
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure where your problem is. However I had this pseudo code which will help you to understand actionlistner on Jcombobox

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ChangeJlableByJComboBox extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ChangeJlableByJComboBox() {
        super("TooltipInSwing");
        setSize(400, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        final JLabel b1;
        final JComboBox jb1 = new JComboBox(new String[] { " ", "one", "two",
                "three" });

        b1 = new JLabel("Default Lable");
        getContentPane().add(b1);
        getContentPane().add(jb1);

        jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // setting custom text to JLabel
                if (jb1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("one"))
                    b1.setText("Lable one ---");
                else if (jb1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("two"))
                    b1.setText("Lable two ---");
                else if (jb1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("three"))
                    b1.setText("Lable three ---");
                else
                    b1.setText("----");

                // or Compact version for setting JcomboBox selected item 
                // to JLabel text

                // b1.setText(jb1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                System.out.println(jb1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                // you can also make use of following method
                System.out.println(jb1.getSelectedIndex());
            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ChangeJlableByJComboBox();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be the same just get the value in the box with getSelectedValue