# How to make a Jbutton clickable and display text

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to create a image JButton clickable and display text once it has been clicked, but I can not seem to figure out how to make it work. I am very new to java so plenty of basic explanations would be very helpful to me. here is the code I am currently working with.

```
 import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class States extends JFrame {
  private JTabbedPane jtpFigures = new JTabbedPane();


  //State Labels


    private JButton VTPanel = new JButton();
     frame.add(VTPanel);
  VTPanel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent);
    System.out.println("The State Capital of VT is Montpelier");
}



  private JButton NYPanel = new JButton();
  private JButton CAPanel = new JButton();
  private JButton MEPanel = new JButton();
  private JButton NHPanel = new JButton();
  private JButton CTPanel = new JButton();
  private JButton MAPanel = new JButton();
  private JButton FLPanel = new JButton();
  private JButton HIPanel = new JButton();
  private JButton NDPanel = new JButton();

  //Images for each of the states
  private ImageIcon[] stateImage = {
    new ImageIcon("image/VT.png"),
    new ImageIcon("image/NY.png"),
    new ImageIcon("image/CA.png"),
    new ImageIcon("image/ME.png"),
    new ImageIcon("image/NH.png"),
    new ImageIcon("image/CT.png"),
    new ImageIcon("image/MA.png"),
    new ImageIcon("image/FL.png"),
    new ImageIcon("image/HI.png"),
    new ImageIcon("image/ND.png")};



    public States() {

        //adds each of the images to the panel
        VTPanel.setIcon(stateImage[0]);
        NYPanel.setIcon(stateImage[1]);
        CAPanel.setIcon(stateImage[2]);
        MEPanel.setIcon(stateImage[3]);
        NHPanel.setIcon(stateImage[4]);
        CTPanel.setIcon(stateImage[5]);
        MAPanel.setIcon(stateImage[6]);
        FLPanel.setIcon(stateImage[7]);
        HIPanel.setIcon(stateImage[8]);
        NDPanel.setIcon(stateImage[9]);



    //Adds the panels and name
        add(jtpFigures, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jtpFigures.add(VTPanel, "Vermont");
        jtpFigures.add(NYPanel, "New York");
        jtpFigures.add(CAPanel, "California");
        jtpFigures.add(MEPanel, "Maine");
        jtpFigures.add(NHPanel, "New Hampshire");
        jtpFigures.add(CTPanel, "Connecticut");
        jtpFigures.add(MAPanel, "Massachusetts");
        jtpFigures.add(FLPanel, "Florida");
        jtpFigures.add(HIPanel, "Hawaii");
        jtpFigures.add(NDPanel, "North Dakota");


        //Sets the default index
        jtpFigures.setSelectedIndex(3);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        States frame = new States();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle("State License Plates");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(560,250);

    }
}
```

Comment: `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent);` should be `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){....}` otherwise it wont compile.

Comment: And our question is where do you want to display your text?

Comment: Duplicate - same question asked 4 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217903/changing-image-to-jbutton-that-will-pop-up-text

Comment: @Smit - I would want it to the right of the image button
.

Comment: @camickr - my apologies, I'm fairly new to his forum and I'm still trying to figure out how to get to my other question, but you linked me to it! thanks

Comment: @Bwan look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047518/how-to-create-a-combo-box-actionlistener/16047698#16047698). Could help you out to sort your problem on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a actionlistener to your button. There is a good reference here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html